# First DropDown selection doesnt trigger the second DropDown function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have 2 DropDowns in MVC and trying to use AngularJS. My first DropDown gets filled with data that comes from the DB properly. When the user makes a selection on the first DropDown, the second DropDown should be filled according to the selection. But, it doesnt get triggered. What am I doing wrong?

When I select from the first DropDown, Chrome Console show this error "undefined". But, it is defined, why does it show this error?

here is my html code...

```
<form name="mainForm" ng-controller="PriceListEditController" novalidate>
    <div class="error">{{message}}</div>
    <select id="brandSelect" ng-model="brandSelect" ng-options="b.Id as b.Name for b in brands" ng-change="GetBrandPriceList()">
        <option value="">Marka Seçiniz</option>
        <option ng-repeat="b.Id for b in brands" value="{{b.Id}}">{{b.Name}}</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="priceList" ng-options="b.Id as b.Name for b in priceLists">
        <option value="">-- Select Country --</option>
        <option ng-repeat="p.Id for p in priceLists" value="{{p.Id}}">{{p.Name}}</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

here is my JS code...

```
var app = angular.module('PriceListEditModule', []);
app.controller('PriceListEditController', ["$scope", "$q", "$http", function ($scope, $q, $http) {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/GetBrands'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.brands = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error ' + response.message;
    });

    $scope.GetBrandPriceList = function () {

        console.log($scope.brandSelect);

        var brandId = $scope.brandSelect;

        if (brandId>0) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/GetBrandPriceList'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.priceLists = response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error ' + response.message;
            });
        }
        else {
            $scope.priceList = null;
        }
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use ng-options and ng-repeat in the same select section.
Try this in you html:

```
<form name="mainForm" ng-controller="PriceListEditController" novalidate>
        <div class="error">{{message}}</div>
        <select id="brandSelect" ng-model="brandSelect" ng-change="GetBrandPriceList()">
            <option value="">Marka Seçiniz</option>
            <option ng-repeat="b in brands" value="{{b.Id}}">{{b.Name}}</option>
        </select>
        test
        <select ng-model="priceList">
            <option value="">-- Select Country --</option>
            <option ng-repeat="p in priceLists" value="{{p.Id}}">{{p.Name}}</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```